# Inner join not working. Output repeating rows

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to get the the students number & name with the course code & name for students who have a grade below 40. This is what i have

```
              SELECT S.name, S.no, C.code, C.name, T.grade
              FROM student S INNER JOIN course C INNER JOIN take T
              WHERE grade <40;
```

It is outputting the grades under 40 but it is returning 128 rows showing everyone's name and number grade repeating them.

Sorry if this is wrong but im a beginner.

Comment: *Never*  use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: what table does grade belong?

Comment: @NilesTanner grade is on the 'take' table

Comment: You're missing the joining conditions that relate the tables to each other.

Comment: @Barmar Can you show me?

Comment: I posted an answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the conditions that relate the tables to each other:

```
SELECT S.name, S.no, C.code, C.name, T.grade
FROM student AS s
JOIN take AS t ON t.student_no = s.no
JOIN course AS c ON t.course_code = c.code
```

Replace `student_no` and `course_code` with the actual foreign key columns in the `take` table.

Comment: Getting the error "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't.student_no' in 'on clause"

Comment: I had to make up some of the missing columns, replace them with the actual columns in your table.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help got it all working now you legend.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple syntax refer it 



 SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Shippers.ShipperName
FROM ((Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID);
```

Comment: I am using 3 tables so where does table3 go?